# click function is not working on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

i am trying to make a list and submit button and the user enters the list size and then after clicking on a button the form is submitted (list size is sent to the servlet ) and an alert should appear .. but the alert is not working .. here is my code

```
<body>

<form action="ServerSide" method="post">
    Enter list Size:<input type="text" name="listsize"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btn">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        alert("anything");
    });
});

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Use the Developer Tools in your browser. Look at the Console. What does it say?

Comment: what do you expect that to do?

Comment: This function looks like it should work. Try changing the `alert` to `console.log("anything");`. Maybe your browser is suppressing the alerts because it's an annoying JavaScript artifact.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy after submitting the form the alert should appear

Comment: That is a submit button, postBack wil be happened, page will be refreshed. If you want to do as you are asking, you have to go with ajax.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy — Nonsense, `alert` is a blocking function.

Comment: @Quentin No one is going to give an alert in a click event handler of a submit button. Probably OP is going to do something else in the place of alert. At that point of time my statement would help him. I hope OP is not going to interpret my comment in a nonsensical way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        alert("Submitted");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="">
  First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Also read this document [DOCS](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_submit)

Answer (score -1):

First of all make sure you are including/referencing JQuery Libray before you use JQuery. it should work.
 
**Secondly you can use this**

```
<body>

<form action="ServerSide" method="post" id="myform">
    Enter list Size:<input type="text" name="listsize"> 
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").on('click',(function(){
        alert("anything");
    }));
});

    </script>

</body>
```

I also notice that  you had used input type submit it will submit form instead of calling click function. you should change type to button

if you want to do something on form submission you have to use onsubmit event

```
<body>

    <form action="ServerSide" method="post" id="myform">
        Enter list Size:<input type="text" name="listsize"> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myform").submit(function(){
            alert("anything");
        });
    });

        </script>

    </body>
```

For this you don't need to add click listener on the submit button. once you submit form it will show you alert.

Comment: If you down vote any answer kindly mention the reason kindly. clicking a button much easy.this is helping platform make sure you help some one.